# How to speed up SQL query with date GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, date, indexing

I have a normal SQLite database table called table1 with 7 columns and of course a rowid. The first column is an custom_id number, the second is date in format YYYY-MM-DD and other 5 are real number data columns. There are about 10M rows in the database, and custom_id and date columns have indices.

What I want to do is to speed up the following query:

```
SELECT date,max(data1) AS maximum
FROM table1
WHERE custom_id = '1123' AND data1 <> 'NaN'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date)
```

I want to find the maximum correct (not NaN) data1 value for the custom_id 1123 for each year-month-combination. The code above works actually fine, but the query lasts 10 seconds in the first run, but the second time it takes under 1 second, which is OK for me. I run the query in my home PC Apache server with PHP. I think Apache uses some caching which explains the difference.

But the question is, how to speed up the first time run performance? I have many other custom_id:s to query, not all can be cached! Do I need more indices? Another kind of query?

Comment: Why do you have `date` and `date1`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - `date` (d-a-t-e) and `data1` (d-a-t-a) which is a numeric value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have date and 5 data columns data1, data2, data3, data4 and data5. Do I have to create 5 indices for each data column? table1(custom_id, data1), table1(custom_id, data2)... That would increase the file size drastically. Currently the file size is about 900 megabytes. I would not like to go over 2 gigabytes, if I have to use more indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to create an index that will support the following operations:

1. Retrieve the records of a specific customer
2. aggregate by month

Creating the following index is not possible since `strftime` is not a deterministic function

```
create index table1_ix on table1 (custom_id,strftime('%Y-%m', date));
```

> non-deterministic functions prohibited in index expressions

So instead of `strftime('%Y-%m', date)` we are going to use `substr(date,1,7)`

```
create index table1_ix on table1 (custom_id,substr(date,1,7));
```

The query should be changed accordingly

```
select      substr(date,1,7), max(data1) as maximum
from        table1
where       custom_id = '1123' 
        and data1 <> 'NaN'
group by    substr(date,1,7)
```

Comment: I got the following error: SQLite3::query(): `Unable to prepare statement: 11, malformed database schema (table1_ix2) - near "(": syntax error` However, index was created successfully according to SQLitebrowser.

Comment: Why are you trying to create the first index?!

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you mean by the first index. I ran this `create index table1_ix on table1 (custom_id,substr(date,1,7));` and SQlitebrowser created it.

Comment: No, you ran `create index table1_ix on table1 (custom_id,strftime('%Y-%m', date));` and I know it because I accidentally left the index name as `table1_ix2` (I already edited the answer and changed it)

Comment: OK, now I understand. However, I'm pretty sure the index is correct (here's a capture) http://imgur.com/a/2JPuP. And the result is this `Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 11, malformed database schema (table1_ix) - near "(": syntax error in`

Comment: This is a tested code (syntax and performance). It was tested on SQLite 3.15.1

Comment: Hmm, is my SQLcipher version too old? SQLiteborwser shows the version 3.11.0.

Comment: Or could the problem be in the PHP SQLite library (too old)?

Comment: "The ability to index expressions was added to SQLite with version 3.9.0 (2015-10-14)" https://sqlite.org/expridx.html

Comment: Darn, PHP's version is  3.8.10.2

Comment: Indexing the `date` in any form is of marginal benefit unless your index also includes `data1` (see my answer). The date is ***not a filtering column***. So all rows filtered by `custom_id = ?` have to be processed. The only overhead without `date` index is that an O(1) hashing function is required to aggregate `max(data1)`. The overhead of maintaining the index through updates is likely to outweigh this marginal benefit.

Comment: @CraigYoung. Since SQLite does not support hash aggregation, indexing by `substr(date,1,7)` eliminates the need to sort the records in order to implement sort aggregation, therefore boost the performance significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is what you intend:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date), max(data1) AS maximum
FROM table1
WHERE custom_id = 1123 AND data <> 'NaN'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date)
```

Start with an index on `table1(custom_id, date)`.

Comment: Indexing on date is not relevant to this query